# Does Fred Flintstone give birth to three babies? If yes how?

Tags: the-flintstones

In a certain episode, Fred becomes a school bus driver. At the end of a tiring day, he picks up a woman. The chapter ends with Fred in the hospital, appearing to have (bizarrely and absurdly) given birth to 3 babies. This is followed by his wife praising him and Fred naming the three babies after himself.

Can someone explain what happened in this seemingly bizarre episode?

Comment: It’d help a lot of if you told us which certain episode you are talking about. Do you have a title or a number?

Comment: I am sorry I dont

Comment: Is this science fiction, or fantasy?

Comment: The Flintstones is definitely fantasy. It's set in a world that drastically differs from any world that exists or has ever existed.

Comment: @workerjoe that could be a whole new question all by itself.  Did humanity recreate dinosaurs and regress to cavemen?  (Sci-fi)   Or did the dinosaur extinction not happen (thus being an alternate history)   Its worth asking IMO.

Comment: ...or was it just an allegory for modern life, based only very very loosely on prehistoric themes, with no real attempt at accuracy or plausibility?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was a space alien in some of the later episodes, idk if that helps resolve the issue

Comment: They went to the moon once

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happens in season 2 episode 3, ["The Missing Bus"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0580270/), and no, Fred does not give birth to babies. The [fandom page for the episode](https://flintstones.fandom.com/wiki/The_Missing_Bus) notes the ending as:

> When Fred successfully assists one of the mothers of his charges in a search for her missing boy, she goes into labor and requires immediate transport on Fred's bus to hospital, where she gives birth to triplets, and Fred is a hero.

So, it is the mother who Fred has on the bus who goes into labour and who has the triplets. Fred is just there because he drove her. He also happens to be their Godparent. Presumably Fred has a hand in naming them because of that and him being the hero that drove them there.

> **Nurse:** Oh, Mr. Flintstone would you like to see your godchildren now?
>
> **Wilma:** You mean they were a pair?
>
> **Fred:** Better than a pair, three of a kind.
>
> **Wilma:** Oh, they're cute. What are their names?
>
> **Fred:** What else? Fred, Fred, and Fred.
>
> **Wilma:** Three Freds? But isn't that confusing?
>
> **Fred:** Yes, considering that they're all girls.
>
> <sub>*The Flintstones*, Season 2 Episode 3, "The Missing Bus"</sub>

Comment: LMAO . Well,  why are the three babies named after Fred  ?

Comment: And driving a woman to the hospital doesn't make them a hero lol

Comment: And why is Fred also hospitalized  ?

Comment: @TheMadHatter Fred isn't hospitalized, he's just in the hospital with the woman.

Comment: Absolutely Bizarre. 3 Female Freds. I am DEAD.xd

Comment: Now [George](https://abc13.com/freeda-foreman-george-daughter-dead/5180451/) on the other hand...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - [George](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Fayne)?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: The linked article comments on how George Foreman named all of his sons "George" (although the article is about the sad news that one of his daughters, all of which got unique names, committed suicide).

Comment: How very sad. ..lol